# How to design page that have many ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to ask how to design a page that have many ajax call. for example 10 ajax call in one page that have function of CRUD..

Currently i have this kind of custom setup:

```
$('[data-ajaxform]').submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();

if(!$(this).parsley().validate()){
    return false;
}

var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr('action'),
    method = $this.attr('method'),
    container = $this.data('container');

if(typeof container !== undefined && container !== false)
    container = '.panel-body';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: method,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $this.serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $this.find(container).append('<div class="indicator show"><span class="spinner spinner1"></span></div>')
    },
})
.done(function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find(container).prepend(data.responseText);
    }, 1000);
    $this.trigger('reset');
    hasValue($this.data('ajaxform'))
})
.fail(function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find(container).prepend(data.responseText);
    }, 1000);
})
.always(function(data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find('.indicator').remove();
    }, 1000);
});

return false;
});
```

Can you guys suggest to me what good practice to implement in doing this or some articles that can help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Articles about asynchronous requests in general can be found using Google. From what I see you use jQuery which makes almost all the job for you. Designing the whole CRUD app relies heavily on it's exact behaviour which you didn't state. Also it depends on the design of the backend which you probably didn't consider.

Answer (score 0):

As not much detail is provided, I can be more generic in my response. Previously when dealing with problem much like yours, I wrap jQuery's `.ajax()` into a global function that accepts custom parameters and/or callback functions, which alter the message sent and the resulting behavior.

```
function myajax(data, callback /*or wrap all stuff in an object literal*/) {
  //any preprocessing or conditionals
  //for example put your setting the url, method, container here
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: callback
  });
}
```

In short, avoid `.ajax()` boilerplate throughout your code by using it only once and make it generic and flexible.